# Silverlight Wait for Multiple Objects to Trigger Loaded Event

Tags: silverlight

In my silverlight application I need to wait for multiple objects to finish load before I continue execution. I tried use ManualResetEvent this way:

```
ManualResetEvent _waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
int objectsToLoad = 0;
int objectsLoaded = 0;

private void MethodA() 
{
   // do stuff

   // count number of objects to Load and set objectsToLoad       
   objectsToLoad = x;

   // change multiple objects interface which should trigger ObjectLoaded

   // wait for all objects trigger loaded event
   _waitHandle.WaitOne();
   _waitHandle.Reset();
}

private void ObjectLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   objectsLoaded ++;
   if (objectsToLoad == objectsLoaded )
   {
      objectsToLoad = 0;
      objectsLoaded = 0;
      _waitHandle.Set();
   }
}
```

But **when I use ManualResetEvent** the ObjectLoaded is not beeing triggered, it seems like the application gets stuck on WaitOne.

Am I using the wrong approach? How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the ManualResetEvent, as you've noticed, it won't allow the message pump (the GUI) to process and you'll never get any further as the other things you're waiting for require the message pump to be active.
Just use either a integer and increment it for every finished event and put code it on each event to check if the value is the count you're looking for. Or, use separate bools and check if all are true on each event.

Comment: The problem is that I need to continue execution from the place where I putted the "_waitHandle.WaitOne();". So, unfortunately, knowing when all events are loaded on the ObjectLoaded method isn't very helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, anything preventing the function from completing will stop WPF from further processing. As far as I know, there isn't any way around this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment to the first answer here, a not-so-elegant approach would be to have a while loop that has the format `while(objectsToLoad != objectsLoaded)`. Inside the while loop, place something like a thread sleep for a few hundred milliseconds so that you aren't pegging the while loop condition. That allows MethodA to maintain the next point of execution while the Loaded event handlers eventually make the condition true for the while loop.

```
int objectsToLoad = 0;
int objectsLoaded = 0;

private void MethodA() 
{
   // do stuff

   // count number of objects to Load and set objectsToLoad       
   objectsToLoad = x;

   // change multiple objects interface which should trigger ObjectLoaded

   // wait for all objects trigger loaded event
   while(objectsToLoad != objectsLoaded)
   {
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
   }
}

private void ObjectLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   objectsLoaded ++;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? I'm afraid that simply sleeping will not solve the issue since sleep does not pump the messages.

Comment: I have not tried it in this specific scenario, no. I have used a similar construct before though and have had success. The more elegant thing to do would be to create a delegate/handler that handles an "everything is done" event from the ObjectLoaded handler if it satisfies the count matching. If it needs context from MethodA, then you can do two things: 1) Refactor the logic that needs to occur after all controls have loaded by moving it outside of MethodA; 2) Define an action at the class level and define it as a lambda in MethodA, giving you closure to variables inside MethodA.